# How prevent duplicate items listView C#

Tags: c#, listview, duplicates

I am using `Windows Forms`. With this code I add items to `listView` from `comboBox`.

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Text = comboBox1.Text;
lvi.SubItems.Add("");
lvi.SubItems.Add("");
lvi.SubItems.Add("");
lvi.SubItems.Add("")

if (!listView1.Items.Contains(lvi))
{
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

I need prevent duplicate items but not work, How Can I solve this?

Comment: The `Contains` checks whether the *reference* exists, not a "similar" item with the same `.Text` and (maybe) similar subitems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `ContainsKey(string key)` instead of `Contains(ListViewItem item)`

```
var txt = comboBox1.Text;

if (!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(txt))
{
    lvi.Text = txt;

    // this is the key that ContainsKey uses. you might want to use the value 
    // of the ComboBox or something else, depending the combobox is freetext 
    // or regarding your scenario.
    lvi.Name = txt;

    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");

    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The ListView class provides a few way to check if an item exists:

- [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.contains.aspx) On [`Items collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx), and
- [`FindItemWithText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext.aspx) methods

It can be used like :

```
// assuming you had a pre-existing item
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("item_key");
if (item == null)
{
    // item does not exist
}


// you can also use the overloaded method to match subitems
ListViewItem item = ListView1.FindItemWithText("sub_item_text", true, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me:

```
if(DialogResult.OK == fileDialogue.ShowDialog())
            {
                foreach (var v in fileDialogue.FileNames)
                {
                    if (listView.FindItemWithText(v) == null)
                    {
                        listView.Items.Add(v);
                    }

                    else
                    //Throw error message
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!listView1.Items.Any(i => i.text == lvi.text))
{
    listView1.items.Add(lvi)
}
```

I'm just guessing on the text property, but I'm pretty sure that's there.

Alternatively - just have a `List<string>` and use it as a data source for your list.

Answer (score 0):

```
String csVal = Value;
ListViewItem csItem = new ListViewItem(csVal);
if (!listViewABC.Items.ContainsKey(csVal))
{
    csItem.Name = csVal;
    listViewABC.Items.Add(csItem );
}
```