# OpenFileDialog - selecting same file twice

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, openfiledialog

I am developing a windows forms application which uses `OpenFileDialog` to select files and drop it to a `ListView`.

The user should not be able to add same file to the `listview` twice. This should NOT happen:

[image: This should NOT happen!!!!]

How can this be done??

Comment: Check against the files existing in the listview before you add another one?

Comment: Again -1, I fail to understand the reason behind this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this code.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    var file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    if (listView1.FindItemWithText(file) == null)
        listView1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

You can also add `else` with a message box informing user about choosing a duplicate file.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried checking if the `listview` contains the file before adding a new one?

The `openfiledialog` lets you filter by extension, but not by file name so you need to process the user selection after it closes. Perhaps showing a message dialog to tell the user that they selected a duplicate would be the best way to handle the invalid selection.

Comment: That is absolutely correct. The problem was to specify the condition for the same message box.

Comment: Bwahahaha. Maybe next time sir. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check against existing entries.

```
var txt = comboBox1.Text;

if (!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(txt))
{
    lvi.Text = txt;

    // this is the key that ContainsKey uses. you might want to use the value 
    // of the ComboBox or something else, depending the combobox is freetext 
    // or regarding your scenario.
    lvi.Name = txt;

    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");
    lvi.SubItems.Add("");

    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

[How prevent duplicate items listView C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290779/how-prevent-duplicate-items-listview-c-sharp)

Comment: Won't work. `Items` is of the `ListViewItemCollection` and `Contains` takes `ListViewItem` type parameter.

Comment: That is why i stated "along those lines", I would give the entire code if my VS would work