# Remove duplicates entries from the ListView in form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview, duplicates

I have a set of code which lists the users details in a list view from a database, it works however multiple entries are often added in when the user clicks to register. How can i get it to work so that the listview knows the name is already present and stops adding mutliple entries into the listview?

this is the code i have for the list view:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
            var item = new ListViewItem();
            item.Text = reader["SSN"].ToString();        // 1st column text
            item.SubItems.Add(reader["FirstName"].ToString());// 2nd column text
            item.SubItems.Add(reader["LastName"].ToString());// 3rd column text
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290779/how-prevent-duplicate-items-listview-c-sharp

Comment: [ListViewItemCollection.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.contains.aspx) and [ListViewItem.FindItemWithText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.finditemwithtext.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You should check manually duplicate entries before adding:

```
if(!listView1.Items.ContainsKey(stringToInsert))
{
    listView1.Items.Add(stringToInsert);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading these from a database you should have a primary key value of sorts, even if it's a mere incremental integer value.

While your `ListView` can contain `ListViewItem` populated from your database, it would be wise to store the actual data models themselves in a collection. I would suggest a `Dictionary` for this, and it would be relatively simple to check for duplicates this way.

For example:

```
class UserModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string SSN { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `Form`, you could have a member variable like so:

```
Dictionary<int, UserModel> users = new Dictionary<int, UserModel>();

void AddItemToList(UserModel model)
{
    if(users.ContainsKey(model.Id)) return; // avoid duplicates

    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem();

    listViewItem.Text = model.SSN;
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(model.FirstName);
    listViewItem.SubItems.Add(model.LastName);

    listView.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

In addition, you should be loading your `UserModel` from the database.