# Why "ContainsKey" does not work when I try to prevent duplicate items to be inserted in a listview?

Tags: c#, winforms

Okay so I have searched anywhere on how to prevent insertion of duplicate listview items, However I found this code from an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290779/how-prevent-duplicate-items-listview-c-sharp).

So here is how I did on my code...

```
if (listView1.Items.ContainsKey(txtBrand.Text.Trim().ToString()))
{
    MessageBox.Show("This brand is already added!");
}

else if (txtBrand.Text.Trim() != "")
{
    ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(txtBrand.Text.Trim());
    listView1.Items.Add(list);
    txtBrand.Text = null;
}
```

I wonder how it worked for others but not on mine, or am I just missing something? Please help

[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing some code at the end of the first line. Can you [edit] and add it in?

Comment: WPF or WinForms?

Comment: It is a WinForm

Comment: In practice you would usually use a DB as the datasource. And the DBMS itself is usually the best place to place these kinds of Limitations. Moving these kinds of checks into the Client will only cause issues like Race Conditions, different implementations between Clients. Extra Network load. "add Brand" would logically be a "Insert & retrieve full list" operation in such a scenario.

Comment: Yes. But that was not my case though, I am using mySQL here. I used the `ListView` on a purpose of multiple inserts, at the same time by filtering out the data entries when the user is still adding an item to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your `ListViewItem`, set the `Name` property. `ContainsKey` does not look at the `Text`.

[See the documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1)

For example, do this:

```
string brand = txtBrand.Text.Trim();
ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(brand);
listItem.Name = brand;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, can you rephrase or explain it to me more? I don't really get it

Comment: When I did that i can't insert new item in the listview

Comment: @Mr.Benbenbenbenben what error/exceptions do you get?

Comment: None, I didn't get any. Btw  I replaced my code on my `else if` with the code you gave me.

Comment: Did you make sure you still added the ListViewItem to the ListView when you replaced your code with Daniel A. White's suggestion? Also, use a breakpoint and check that your ListView has items, and check the key's of each along with the Name property of each individual ListViewItem.

Comment: Oh I get it, I should have just added it instead of replacing the code from `else if`

Comment: @Mr. Moose no i didn't because i removed it earlier, but as of now I got it to work correctly